# Read unicode string from file to CComBSTR

Tags: c++, mfc

I save a long string of unicode format in a file.
How can I read the data from the file into CComBSTR?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0dsx8by%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
OLECHAR* str = OLESTR("ta ta");  // wide char string of length 5
CComBSTR bstr2(wcslen(str));     // unintialized BSTR of length 5
wcscpy(bstr2.m_str, str);        // copy wide char string to BSTR
```

Comment: Thansks, I also have a problem reading the unicode data from the file into str. My file contains onlt one string (very long string), in unicode. How can I read it into str? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`BSTR` strings use UTF-16 for their character encoding.  If the file data also uses UTF-16, then just read the file data as-is into the `BSTR` memory directly, eg:

```
CComBSTR bstr(fileSize / 2);
ReadFile(..., bstr.m_str, fileSize, ...);
```

However, if the file is using a different character encoding, then call `MultiByteToWideChar()` to calculate the necessary length to allocate the `BSTR` memory, then call `MultiByteToWideChar()` a second time to decode the file data into the `BSTR` memory, eg:

```
int bstrLen = MultiByteToWideChar(fileDataCodepage, 0, fileData, fileSize, NULL, 0);
CComBSTR bstr(bstrLen);
MultiByteToWideChar(fileDataCodepage, 0, fileData, fileSize, bstr.m_str, bstrLen);
```