# MFC read unicode string from file into string

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a file that contains a very long unicode string.
I want to read the whole unicode string from the file into string (or CString).
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read unicode string from file to CComBSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710442/read-unicode-string-from-file-to-ccombstr)

Answer (score 1):

Use MFC's CFile to open the file
call CFile::GetStatus to acquire file size http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0hc0ht%28VS.80%29.aspx
allocate a BYTE array of the acquired file size and use CFile::Read to get it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwbccf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Now there's a BOM issue you need to take care of.  Check if the BOM chars exists in the beginning of your buffer.  Since you did not specify what unicode format is your file, you'll need to refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark to figure out what they are.  Remove BOM chars before going on.

Now you can try to throw the raw buffer into CString constructor.  Most of the time this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream file("filename.txt");
char data[1024];
file.read(data, 1024);
CString str(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CString lv_szResult;

CStdioFile lv_InputFile( c_szFile, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeUnicode );
CString lv_szLine ;
while( lv_InputFile.ReadString( lv_szLine ) == TRUE )
{
  lv_szResult += lv_szLine + "\n" ;
}
```